# OpenStack neutron subnet - create port with ip address after network address

Tags: mariadb, openstack-neutron

I have this neutron private subnet 10.200.206.0/23
when I created a port using this subnet, it should give me 10.200.206.1 as I expected since nobody uses this .1 ip yet.

**Instead it gave me 10.200.206.20**

Note this subnet had been used previously and deleted all ports/ip that used by other instances. I am 100% that this ip 10.200.206.1 is not in-used.

DHCP is disabled.

Can we actually reset the old info from this subnet in OpenStack DB backend?

Comment: How is it related to MariaDB for which it's tagged?

Comment: MariaDB is the replacement of mysql. OpenStack DBs are stored inside MariaDB? keystone, nova,neutron,cinder etc...

Answer (score 0):

Once you start using a subnet, Neutron DB will keep track of used IP addresses and doesn't reassign until all the addresses are used once.

Easiest way to reset is to remove the subnet and recreate it again.